# PasswordSignInAsync tries to create new database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I'm working on an existing project with Windows Authentification and existing database (so we are in database first for entity framework). 
Now we are changing the authentification way for the OWIN Identity Authentication.

 
 
After following some tutorials, I got this new context for my asp identity tables:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("myconnexionstring", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
       Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

myconnexionstring is exactly the same as my original context generated by the EDMX in Database-first.

I also turned the migrations enable thanks of the Package Manager Console and play a migration to create the asp identity tables in my database. No problem for this part.

This is my StartupClass:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        this.ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/LogOn"),
            CookieName = "MyCookie",
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    }
}
```

Now when I try to authenticate me, I get an exception with this message: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. This exception occurs when I call the **PasswordSignInAsync** method of my **ApplicationSignInManager**

This is my LoginController class:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set { _signInManager = value; }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult LogOn(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> LogOn(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // the SqlException throw there 
            SignInStatus result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false, false); 
            if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Adress invalid");
            return View(model);
        }
    }


    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my ApplicationSignInManager:

```
 public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
   : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

The ApplicationUserManager:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>());
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
        //manager.EmailService = new EmailService();

        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

The ApplicationUser:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Any idea to help me ? It shouldn't try to create database but only sign the user in.

**EDIT**

The exception occurs the first time the database is called. 
This is my connexion string:

```
<add name="myconnexionstring" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DbModel.csdl|res://*/DbModel.ssdl|res://*/DbModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Database2014;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=MyPassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**EDIT 2** 
My new connexion string

```
<add name="myconnexionstringForIdentity" connectionString="data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Database2014;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=MyPassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And I changed the ApplicationDbContext:

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("myconnexionstringForIdentity", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
       Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: SignInAsync is the first time the database is called. What is your connectionstring?

Comment: Thank you Richard. Yes it is the first time. The user is not authenticated so  he is redirected on the login page. So he tries to log in but the exceptions occurs. 

I edit for the connexion string

Answer (score 0):

Asp.Net Identity uses Code First which uses a normal connection string, the provided connection string is for a database first.

Try to add another connection string but remove all the other stuff related to DB First and keep only the data source and catalog, then update your class to have the new connection string name

Comment: Thank you for your help Haitham. I did a second string connexion for code first. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Would you add the connection string here? did you update the ApplicationDbContext  class constructor with the new connection string name?